# Spring Boot Ignoring Configuration Bean, Or Building in Wrong Order?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a JHipster 5.3.4 project with fairly standard config and security config, but when trying to run the project, I get the following error signifying a missing bean.

in **root/config/SecurityConfiguration.java** I have the following class header and internal bean

```
@Configuration
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
...
}
```

And in **root/web/rest/UserJWTController.java** I have the following

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserJWTController {
   private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
   private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

   public UserJWTController(TokenProvider tokenProvider, 
                            AuthenticationManager  authenticationManager) {
       this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
       this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
   }
...
```

But when I try to run the project I get:
**Parameter 1 of constructor in au.com.suncorp.pp.web.rest.UserJWTController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager'**

I'm assuming there's a bean build ordering problem, but I'm out of my element. Can someone please assist?

Comment: Remove  authenticationManagerBean()

Comment: Why? That's the only constructor for the AuthenticationManager anywhere in the app. Where else would it go?

Comment: Before you ask the question, have you tried to remove it and see if there is any error?

Comment: Exact same error as before.

Comment: What is the exact code in UserJWTController  which needs AuthenticationManager ?

Comment: You try to inject AuthenticationManager  inside SecurityConfiguration  ?
Can you add to your main class @ComponentScan(basesPackages={"the package of your SecurityConfiguration.class"}) then tell us if it work ?

Comment: That's what came in with the default build and setup using guides from the JH devs themselves.

Comment: @Ian, the authorize() method --- Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
       SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

Comment: if it is jhipster code, maybe you should consult in the jhispter chat or mailing list to see if there is any help available?

Comment: try @Autowire in your construction injection.

Comment: This code works well in generated project, so what have you changed?

Answer (score 0):

So UserJWTController is your class, right?

Why don't you autowire?

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Comment: It's already autowired by constructor injection and as supposedly there is only one constructor, `@Autowired` can be omitted  see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Comment: I don't know if there is only one constructor. I can see a few dots